# Where exactly is the prompt of input() written to?

Tags: python

I stumbled upon this because of a [bug report](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/61) I got for a [library](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) where I redirect `stderr` to `os.devnull` on the C level (using CFFI).

The problem is that when using the built-in `input()` function (with the `prompt` argument) after importing my module, the input prompt is apparently also redirected out of view.

The strange thing about this is that the `input()` isn't even supposed to write to `stderr`. The documentation states clearly:

> If the *prompt* argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

I tried to find out where the prompt is written to, but I didn't get any wiser:

```
python3 -c 'print(input("prompt: "))'
python3 -c 'print(input("prompt: "))' > /dev/null
python3 -c 'print(input("prompt: "))' 2> /dev/null
```

The first command shows the prompt (as expected) but it is invisible with both the second and third command.

So is it written to `stdout` or `stderr` or somewhere entirely different?

And what can I do in my library to avoid redirecting it?

BTW, I tested this on macOS and Linux using Python 3.5 (CPython). Python 2.7 (with `raw_input()` instead of `input()`) shows the same behavior.

Comment: I think the prompt may be not displayed when one of the standard output/error streams is not a tty/pty (or I think mismatches the input device?)

Comment: I think it would be a bug in Python itself :-??

Comment: This is caused by the readline library (if `stdin` is connected to a TTY, then readline is used), not Python itself (which would otherwise always use `stdout`. As the duplicate shows, using `import readline` first causes the readline library to be configured differently and the prompt is correctly sent. Another work-around is to disconnect stdin from the tty (with redirection): `echo -n 'foobar' | python -c 'print(input("test"))' 2>/dev/null`